# Recognize SQL injection attack purely based on the sql query string

Tags: node.js, sql-injection

I'm looking for libraries or methods that allow me to recognize `SQL injection` attacks by only looking at the `SQL` query String?  It needs to work on a `nodejs` server.

For example:

```
 SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = '' or 1=1;--' AND password = '7f14034bdfbc7ead000a939e33c72b69'
```

This query is "infected" by an sql injection while this example is not:

```
 SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = 'fdgdfgdg' AND password = '7f14034bdfbc7ead000a939e33c72b69'
```

Comment: With prepared statements there is no mutable query string.

Comment: Yes, if your goal is to protect from sql injection attacks, then use prepared statements. Otherwise, it's an interesting problem to implement yourself.

Comment: I know prepared statements exist and are in many cases the solution. However, I can not use them for this project for some reasons. The application is just a prototype.